# overflow: scroll doesn't seem to work in Chrome with flex display

Tags: css, overflow, flexbox

I have a setup similar to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AZZH8/2/). One of the `div` here has a very long content so I applied `overflow:scroll` to its parent; however, while in Firefox it works perfectly, in Chrome the long content resizes its parent... something I do not want to happen.

I suspect this problem might be related to the fact that I use `display: flex;` on the `body`. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't seem to get any difference between Chrome & FF?

Comment: Is the overflow:scroll applied? I will check on another computer maybe my Chrome is not up to date.

Comment: Indeed, works fine in Chrome 30.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. My guess is that your version of chrome doesn't support the css rule flex

Comment: OK, thanks to both of you! I will make more tests and update my Chrome in case it isn't.

Comment: Just checked: I've got the latest version according to synaptic/aptitude (I'm on Ubuntu), though its version number is not 30.